# JTL-Shop / admin / Login with Traefik not possible

Tags: docker, traefik

I've been trying to solve my problem for days.

I've created a couple of Docker containers and all of them work with the settings without a problem (Shopware, Sulu, Matomo, Mautic) but only the JTL shop gives me problems.
Frontend goes but backend login blocked without error message.

If you had a message you wouldn't have to poke around.

I'll write my docker-compose from Traefik and JTL-Shop here

## Traefik

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    container_name: Traefik
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=info@Example.de"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"

    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      # Routers
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`traefik.example.de`)
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.service: api@internal
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver: myresolver
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares: traefik-auth
      # global redirect to https
      traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule: hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)
      traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints: web
      traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares: redirect-to-https
      # Middleware
      traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.removeheader: true
      traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users: USER:PASSWORT
      # middleware redirect
      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme: https

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

    networks:
      - "traefik_proxy"
      - "default"

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

## ==
JTL shop

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  www-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: ${CONTAINERVOLUMES}/html
  mysql-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: ${CONTAINERVOLUMES}/mysql
  elastic-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: ${CONTAINERVOLUMES}/elastic
  redis-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: ${CONTAINERVOLUMES}/redis

services:
#  sshd:
#    image: hermsi/alpine-sshd
#    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-SSH
#    environment:
#      ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
#    ports:
#      - "${SSH_PORT}:22"
#    volumes:
#      - www-data:/var/www/html

  apache:
    image: webdevops/php-apache:7.4-alpine
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-Apache-PHP
    environment:
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /app/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-Projekt
      PHP_DISMOD:
      PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS: 1
      PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE: Europe/Berlin
      PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 360
      PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 756M
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 64M
      PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 64M
      PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN: 1
    volumes:
      - ./configs/php.ini:/opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - ./configs/root:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root:ro
      - www-data:/app
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy

    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Docker Netzwerk
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy
      # Routers
      - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.rule=${HOSTRULE}
      - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.service=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_SVC
      - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.middlewares=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_MidWa
      - traefik.http.services.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_SVC.loadBalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_MidWa.headers.sslredirect=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_MidWa.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_MidWa.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Ssl=on
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_MidWa.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Port=443

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-MySQL
    # command für mysql 8.x
    # command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-Redis
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

#  elastic:
#    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
#    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-Elastic
#    volumes:
#      - elastic-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#    ulimits:
#      memlock:
#        soft: -1
#        hard: -1
#      nofile:
#        soft: 65535
#        hard: 65535
#    environment:
#      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
#      - discovery.type=single-node
#      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
#    expose:
#      - 9200
#      - 9300

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: ${PROXY_NETWORK}
```

## ==
yesterday I saw these logs in the container when I logged in.
LOGS

```
[httpd:access] www.example.fr:80 93.230.203.21 - 172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:36 +0000] "GET /admin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:782 bytesOut:626 reqTime:0

172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:36 +0000] "GET /admin/templates/bootstrap/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"

[httpd:access] www.example.fr:80 93.230.203.21 - 172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:36 +0000] "GET /admin/templates/bootstrap/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:753 bytesOut:9937 reqTime:0

NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 88 bytes exceeds the limit of 64 bytes in Unknown on line 0

[Sun Oct 25 19:10:49.591342 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 67:tid 140596503538464] [client 172.18.0.2:42418] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 88 bytes exceeds the limit of 64 bytes in Unknown on line 0', referer: https://www.example.fr/admin/index.php

[php-fpm:access] 127.0.0.1 -  25/Oct/2020:19:10:49 +0000 "POST /admin/index.php" 200 /app/JTL4-CeT-Projekt/admin/index.php 149.417 2048 13.39%

172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:49 +0000] "POST /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2162 "https://www.example.fr/admin/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"

[httpd:access] www.example.fr:80 93.230.203.21 - 172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:49 +0000] "POST /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:1066 bytesOut:2531 reqTime:0

172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:50 +0000] "GET /admin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 271 "https://www.example.fr/admin/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"

[httpd:access] www.example.fr:80 93.230.203.21 - 172.18.0.2 - - [25/Oct/2020:19:10:50 +0000] "GET /admin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:782 bytesOut:626 reqTime:0
```

==

Comment: Thanks for providing the logs. However, for security reasons, you'd rather change the hostnames/ip to something else..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried it from the start.
I think that I also have the error now.
When I call the installation routine, my server or container fulfills the requirements.

But I can't install because:

```
The CSS and JS instructions come over HTTP and he sees these urls as unsafe.
```

If I override the protection it loads the pages with the CSS instructions etc. but if I enter the database data it doesn't do it and shows me the same page again as when I logged in.

My question is how do I get Traefik to control the web server via https (internally) so that the installation program does not control http as it does now (internally) for me but changes to https and in the best case also forwards the URL to www.

So the same as the htaccess rules:

```
  # Redirect requests to access the site with HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R] 

  #REWRITE ANPASSUNG 2 (auf www.meinedomain.de umleiten)
  #Ihr Shop sollte nicht unter www.meinedomain.de und nur meinedomain.de erreichbar sein, siehe: http://guide.jtl-software.de/index.php?title=JTL-Shop3-Neuinstallation#4._Einrichtung_einer_Domainweiterleitung
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.fr
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.fr/$1 [r=301,L]
```